# C++ BOOST Unit Tests: Invert BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL for not equal

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

Is there a way to check for inequality when writing Unit Tests with BOOST?

There is a macro `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL`, however there does not appear to be a `BOOST_CHECK_NOT_EQUAL` macro.

I assume it must be possible to check for inequality in a BOOST Unit Test? I could not find anything from a duckduckgo search however.

Comment: I've just discovered that `BOOST_CHECK(a != b)` will also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro you're looking for is `BOOST_CHECK_NE`:

```
BOOST_CHECK_NE(a,b);
BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(a,b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since accepting the answer I have discovered some further information:

```
BOOST_CHECK_NE(a, b)
```

does what I intended to do, however it has the side effect of requiring `a`/`b` to define a stream insertion `operator<<` for whatever type `a`/`b` is.

```
BOOST_CHECK(a != b)
```

doesn't require this, so I went with this option instead.